# Any problems accessing sqlite files directly from Azure file storage?

Tags: sqlite, azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-storage-files

We have a legacy system we're planning on migrating to Azure. The system uses sqlite files to store the data we need to access. After bouncing around with numerous solutions, we've decided to store the sqlite files in Azure file storage and access them via a UNC path from a cloud worker role (we can't use Azure functions or app services as they don't have the ability to use SMB).

This all seems to work ok, but what I'm nervous about is how sqlite is likely to react when trying to access a large file (effectively over a network) this way.

Does anyone have experience with this sort of thing and if so did you come across any problems?

The alternative plan was to use a web worker role and to store the sqlite files in blob storage. In order to access the data though, we'd have to copy the blob to a temp file on the web server machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use Azure File Storage, since it's effectively an SMB share, backed by blob storage (which means it's *durable*). And also, since it's an SMB share, you can then access it from your various worker role instances.

As for your alternate choice (storing in blob and copying to temporary storage) - that won't work, since each worker role instance is independent, and you'd then have multiple, unsynchronized copies of your database on each VM. And if a VM rebooted, you would immediately lose all data on that temporary drive.

Note: With Web/worker role instances, as well as VM's, you can attach a blob-backed disk and store content durably there. However, you'd still have the issue of dealing with multiple instances (because attached disks cannot be attached to multiple VMs).